# Quick Settings Menu has only 3 icons when extended, is there a way to make it 3 by 3?

Tags: quick-settings, android-go, nokia

On my Nokia C20 which runs Android Go 11 when I pull down the quick settings menu there is only 3 items on it, and I cant find a way to change it.
Is there any way I can fix that?
[image: Quick menu screenshot]

Comment: In some Android versions a seconds row appears if you pull down the menu a second time. Not sure in which Android version this was added (or is it a manufacturer modification?) and if it is also available on Android Go.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the gear icon?  It works on my Android.